# build syntaxnet with bazel: pywrap error

Tags: python-2.7, build, bazel, syntaxnet

I am trying to build syntaxnet using bazel without root rights. I have downloaded bazel 0.2.2b and pulled the syntaxnet git repository as suggested on its website. I have managed to [pass the new gcc](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/629) for the bazel build and set my environment variables to include the local gcc as well as my local python version (2.7). I also added swig and jdk to `PATH`. Still, I get the following error when trying to run `bazel test syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...`:

`INFO: Found 65 targets and 12 test targets...
ERROR: /home/davba/.cache/bazel/_bazel_debauscd/33ff1ccf943e8d1167bc44c81c9ea8f4/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:1023:1: output 'external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.cc' was not created.
ERROR: /home/davba/.cache/bazel/_bazel_debauscd/33ff1ccf943e8d1167bc44c81c9ea8f4/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:1023:1: output 'external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py' was not created.
ERROR: /home/davba/.cache/bazel/_bazel_debauscd/33ff1ccf943e8d1167bc44c81c9ea8f4/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/BUILD:1023:1: not all outputs were created.`

After that, none of the tests are run which means all twelve tests are skipped. Any ideas are highly appreciated.

**Edit:** I have realized that I used an old version of protobuf. Unfortunately, the problem remains even after updating.

Since it seems to be a python related problem and I had built python from source, I tried to use anaconda but ended up with the same error.

Some more information: I am using CentOS 6.5 and tried python 2.7.11.
I set the environment variables as follows and changed the CROSSTOOL file for building bazel [accordingly](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/760):

`CXX=/soft/csw/linux64/rel6/gccs-4.8.5/bin/c++`

`CC=/soft/csw/linux64/rel6/gccs-4.8.5/bin/gcc`

`LDFLAGS="-L/soft/csw/linux64/rel6/gccs-4.8.5/lib -L/soft/csw/linux64/rel6/gccs-4.8.5/lib64":"-L/home/davba/syntaxnet-utils/pcre/lib"`

`CXXFLAGS="-L/soft/csw/linux64/rel6/gccs-4.8.5/lib -L/soft/csw/linux64/rel6/gccs-4.8.5/lib64"`

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/soft/csw/linux64/rel6/gccs-4.8.5/lib:/soft/csw/linux64/rel6/gccs-4.8.5/lib64:/home/davba/AnacondaPython/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

`SWIG_PATH=/home/davba/syntaxnet-utils/compiled-swig/bin`

Thanks!

Comment: Can you run `bazel test --verbose_failures syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: Adding the `--verbose_failures`option does not seem to change the error output. I still get the same three errors and the `NO STATUS` message for all tests. However, I have noticed that I use an old version of protobuf. I will try to update and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running it on a different machine with CentOS 7.0, but wound up with the same error.

Finally, I had the opportunity to switch to an Ubuntu machine with sudo rights which enabled me to run the bazel installer and compile syntaxnet without a problem. This solves the problem in my case. For a "real" fix I think we have to wait for someone experiencing the same issue.